# Remove first character from a string

Tags: regex, r

Is there a way to remove or replace with `""`, the `"X"` from the beginning of words?

Ex:

> XN5634_er
>      X123_er
>      NX45

Desired output:

> N5634_er
>      123_er
>      NX45

Totally I have about 14.000 words. I used

```
gsub("X", '', mylist, fixed = T)
```

but `X` is removed from `NX45` too.

Comment: Does `gsub("^X", '', mylist, fixed = T)` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
> mylist <- list("XN5634_er", "X123_er", "NX45")
> gsub("^X", '', mylist)
[1] "N5634_er" "123_er"   "NX45"
```