# Converting strings in list to numeric matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have the following list, and I can't seem to get it converted to a numeric matrix.

```
> MyList
[[1]]
[1] "X4" "X3" "X2" "X5"

[[2]]
[1] "X5" "X2" "X4" "X3"

[[3]]
[1] "X4" "X3" "X2" "X5"
```

I tried `as.matrix(MyList)`, but that still gives me a matrix with strings. What I'm trying to accomplish is a matrix with the numeric values, so "X4" becomes 4, "X3" becomes 3, et cetera. Any suggestions?
Obviously in this code I could easily change it, with my actual code I can't change the output.

Comment: please provide code, otherwise feel my wrath of the down-vote button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the `list`, use `sub` to remove the non-numeric characters and convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric`.

```
lst <- lapply(MyList, function(x) as.numeric(sub("\\D+", '', x)))
lst
#[[1]]
#[1] 4 3 2 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 5 2 4 3

#[[3]]
#[1] 4 3 2 5
```

If we need it to be a `matrix`, either

```
do.call(rbind, lst)
```

Or as @Jaap mentioned in the comments, use `sapply` instead of `lapply` and transpose the output

```
t(sapply(MyList, function(x) as.numeric(sub("\\D+", '', x))))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: `t(sapply(MyList, function(x) as.numeric(sub("\\D+", '', x))))` gives back a matrix

Comment: Just as another suggestion you could extract the first letter of each matrix like so....just to give ideas.


    mylist <- list("X3", "X8", "X9")
    mylist1<- as.numeric(gsub("^X", '', mylist))
    
    mylist1
    
    [1] 3 8 9

Source:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138296/remove-first-character-from-a-string

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess  Yes, or a faster option if it is specific to first letter would be using `substr`

Comment: @akrun How would `substr` be used in this case? Since indeed it always needs to be the first letter.

Comment: @Joseph You could use `lapply(MyList, function(x) as.numeric(substr(x,2, nchar(x))))`